# Translating a mips pseudo instruction 'rol'

Tags: assembly, translation, mips, pseudocode

I'm trying to translate the mips pseudo instruction rol (rotate left). I need to translate it before I can submit an assignment, which is unfortunate because the pseudo instruction worked quite well for me.

The instruction was,

```
      rol   $s4,$s4, 1  #goes to the left most bit (which as it says, gets the left most bit)
```

the way I translated it was,

```
       lui $s4, 0x8001     
       ori $t0, $s4, 0x0004
       srl $s4, $t0, 31
       sll $s5, $t0, 1
       or $s5, $s5, $s3
```

but it completely messes up my code, can someone please help me translate it correctly? Or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You used `$s3` instead of `$s4` on the last line. I assume the first two instructions are not part of the rotate.

Comment: that was a typo on my behalf when i typed this pseudo code, the registers are correct in the code, it's the translation that's incorrect :\

Comment: Also you are rotating `$t0` not `$s4` and the result is in `$s5`. So, not a drop-in replacement for the original instruction. Please edit the code to show what you actually have.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [UT-Dallas lecture](https://www.utdallas.edu/%7Edodge/EE2310/lec14.pdf) on `Shift` and `Rotate` MIPS instructions/pseudoinstructions.

Slide Nine pulls back the curtain on the `rol`/`ror` pseudoinstruction.

Behind the scenes there are a pair of shifts (`srl` and `sll`) which move relevant bits into their final desired locations and fills non-relevant bit positions with `0`'s, and then an `or` to recombine them with bits rotated as desired.

In your case you want to rotate all bits one position to the left. To create this behavior we can use three MIPS instructions:

```
 # rol $s4, $s4, 1    # expanded as a pseudo-instruction

 srl $at, $s4, 1   #shift original word 1 bit to the right
 sll $s4, $s4, 31  #shift original word 31 bits to the left
 or  $s4, $s4, $at #Combine two fragments of words and place result in source register
```

It needs one temporary register; the other shift result can be written to the eventual destination, using it to hold the other temporary.  This uses `$at` (the "assembler temporary) for thefirst, like other pseudo-instructions such as `blt $reg, $reg, target`.  Writing the destination second avoids destroying it, in case it's also one of the inputs.

Comment: This actually only needs one temporary (other than the destination) to work, so it can work as a pseudo-instruction using `$at`, the assembler-temporary register that other pseudo-instructions use.  Shift one way into `$at`, shift the other way into the `rol` destination, then `or $dst, $dst, $at`.  This works even if `rol` is used with the same source and destination (that's why we shift into `$at` first)

Comment: It has been a few years since I took my "Intro to Computing" course.. I will definitely defer to you! Do you think it makes sense for me to delete the answer?

Comment: No, it's a good answer, just suggesting a tweak to the register usage!

Answer (score 1):

Actually 'rol/ror' is only pseudo-instrations for ISAs before mips32r2 / mips64r2. Release 2 added hardware support for these instructions.

You can always look at rol32 / ror32 in bitops.h in Linux for a C implementation and then dissasemble it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you swapped quite a few things.

The instruction format is:

```
inst rd, rs1, rs2
```

So your code should be:

```
lui $s4, 0x8001     
ori $s4, $t0, 0x0004
sll $s5, $s4, 1
srl $s4, $s4, 31
or $s4, $s5, $s4
```

Also you use the `srl` which is good. That one ignores the sign. Note, however, that I first shift to `s5`, then shift `$s4`.

Also I save the result in `$s4` since your `rol` would do that (and not save in `$s5`.)

Also, to properly simulate your `rol`, you most certainly should use `$t1` (register 1, temporary) and not `$s5` unless you want to save `$s5` on your stack and then restore it...