# mips rotate left pseudo code translation

Tags: assembly, rotation, bit-manipulation, mips

In MIPS assembly code, how would I go about implementing the rotate left pseudo instruction to make bits rotate left?

For instance, if a register contained 0x12345678, a rotate left with a shift amount of 2 would make the register contain 0x34567812.

I understand shift left logical, but the idea of taking the bits that were pushed off during the shift and putting them on the other side is confusing. I have seen this post that may be similar to my question:  [Translating a mips pseudo instruction 'rol'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542657/translating-a-mips-pseudo-instruction-rol)

Except, the answer in this post doesn't make sense to me and I am not sure if their code does what I am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes that code does what you need, but with a shift of 1 bit. The general idea is `(x << n) | (x >> (32 - n))`. I trust you can implement that yourself.

Comment: Wow, when you put it in those terms, the solution makes a lot more sense. Okay, so considering I want to take register $t2 and rotate left $t2 by amount n, and store answer in $t1.  

I completely understand why I should I have this code:

sll $t1, $t2, n
srl $t2, $t2, 32-n
or $t1, $t2, $t1

However, I have no idea why I am supposed to use lui and ori before this. Like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542657/translating-a-mips-pseudo-instruction-rol ,  the answer has:  lui $s4, 0x8001     
ori $s4, $t0, 0x0004

Comment: The `lui/ori` is just to get your input into the appropriate register. MIPS doesn't have 32 bit immediates, you need to load in two halves.

Comment: That makes sense. However, why do you use those specific Hex values for the lui and ori? Would it be different values if you are trying to rotate a different amount besides 1?

Comment: That was the sample **input**. Like, in your example the `0x12345678`. You would do `lui $t2, 0x1234; ori $t2, $t2, 0x5678`. You are overthinking this :)

Comment: Oh gosh I am so sorry! That makes perfect sense. You are right, I am overthinking this! Haha this all makes perfect sense to me now. Thank you so much Jester! Have a nice day!!